Why my CSS is not loading properly the first time?
The context is that I am building a NextJS WebApp and in this application, i have a component page which is going to be a pattern for other three pages, only changing the styles and some other minor things (i'm going to pass props to it). The big problem is that i have a page which load this component, but it's styling (css) doesn't work immedialy, but when i refresh the page, i really don't know what is happening
This is the first page, which calls the page with loading problems
`import audioSoftware from '../assets/audio_software.jpg' 
import eletronicComp from '../assets/eletronic_comp.jpg' 
import guyWithAGuitar from '../assets/guy_with_a_guitar.jpg' 

const path = require('path')

import Link from 'next/link'

import '../styles/landingPage.css'

export default function LandingPage() {

return(
    <div>
        <h1 className='text-center mb-2 text-white text-2xl tracking-wider'>Por onde quer começar a estudar?</h1>
        <div className="container">
            <Link href="/audio_software/post?page=1"> // Here is the Link for the page
                <div className="box box-1">
                    <p>Audio Software</p>
                </div>
            </Link>

            <div className='box box-2'>
                <p>Tecnologia Musical</p>
            </div>

            <div className='box box-3'>
                <p>Composição Eletrônica</p>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

This is the referenced page, which imports the component page
import PagePattern from '../../component/pagePattern'

export default function AudioSoftwarePage(params) {
return(
    <div>
        <PagePattern/>
    </div>
)
}

and here is the component page
'use client'

import Link from 'next/link'
import '../styles/pagePattern.css'

import Image from 'next/image'
import qualquer_img from '../assets/audio_software.jpg'

export default function PagePattern() {

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="container">

                <div className="header">
                    <Link href="/">
                        <h1 id="logo_text">CesMusic</h1>
                    </Link>



                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="search" 
                        id="search" 
                        placeholder="Pesquise alguma postagem aqui" 
                    />

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

